# How to overload effectively and systematically Python class methods

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, overloading, boilerplate

Assume that you have a Python (>=2.6) class with plenty (hundreds!) of methods. Now someone wants to subclass that but realized that most of the base class methods needs only some simple 'tuning'. Also there are only handful of different ways to tune those methods. Some involving input transformations, some output transformations, some both.

To be more specific I'm looking for a (simple) solution for the inheritance where I just could provide the base class and a list (of lists) of methods to apply the specific transformations, without adding this boilerplate code to each overloaded method.

Thanks,
eat

Follow up.
Based on gabo10yf answer, I came up a solution as:

```
class B(object):
    def f1(self, val):
        print '1: ', val
    def f2(self, val):
        print '2: ', val
def decorator(f):
    def g(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'entering'
        result= f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return g

class A(B):
    pass

_overridden= ['f1', 'f2']
def override(cls):
    for name in _overridden:
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(getattr(cls, name).im_func))
override(A)

if __name__== '__main__':
    b= B()
    b.f1(1)
    b.f2(2)
    a= A()
    a.f1(1)
    a.f2(2)
```

It really seems to work. However it feels almost too simple, it surely must still contain some murky issues? Anyway thanks to you all letting me figure out this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
 # the base class
class B(object):
    def f1(self, val):
        pass
    def f2(self, val):
        pass
```

def decorator(cls, f):
    def g(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # do more stuff
    return g

class A(B):
    _overridden = ['f1', 'f2']
    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        for name in cls._overridden:
            setattr(name, decorator(getattr(name).im_func))

A.load()

One may have to do some changes in order to handle class and static methods.

Comment: I think this is so far closest what I'm looking for. However the load method is unacceptable. Its functionality should be executed on (or just after) the class creation. Thanks!

Comment: One can call `load` just after class creation (that's what I'm doin here). You can also use a metaclass to call some `load` method just before class creation (by overriding `type.__new__`) or just after (by overriding `type.__init__`). See: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use some form of Aspected-Oriented Programming. With the [Logilab library](http://www.logilab.org/2738/), it is easy to put wrappers around all methods of a class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Aspect oriented programming might be the to go. But how it's different just using decorators? And my point merely is just how to apply systematic way these aspects (/decorators)? So I'm just avoiding to manually type the boilerplate code.

Comment: Using decorators where exactly? Also, entirely avoiding the boilerplate code is not feasible - you will need to write it down at least once.

Comment: @duffymo: most certainly not. A decorator you put at the function you want to modify. An aspect you put entirely elsewhere, and you use a pointcut language to specify how it acts on the existing classes and methods. You do not modify the file containing the method source to employ aspects, whereas you do have to modify the file with decorators.

Comment: My mistake, Martin.  I understand aspects and Java, but apparently I've missed aspects in Python.  Thank you for the correction.  I'll remove my erroneous comment.

Comment: I studied the Logilab lib and yes it seems allmost to be right tool. But I'm looking for really a simpler solution to include in my own code. Cant expect end users to install additional libs. Anyway good reference for future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider decorators before I'd go for inheritance.

I'd also consider refactoring that class - hundreds of methods suggests "god anti-pattern" to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have access to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

> Assume that you have a Python (>=2.6)
>   class with plenty (hundreds!) of
>   methods

I will then refactor the class, because the class design is broken.

Also, you can easily achieve the given result by [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) an instance of said class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have access to the base class. How would you do this 'monkey patching' systematic(programmable) way in my case?